# Подключение к нескольким серверам баз данных через пул без использование библиотек с открытым исходным кодом в JAVA

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, java-ee, jdbc

Есть (проблем) нужно подключится к нескольким серверам  базам данных  и создать устойчивое соединение  **без использование  библиотек с открытым исходным кодом** , в случае  если один сервер умирает  "Manager" должен автоматически переключиться на второй сервер базы данных и проверяет готовность главного сервера БД к работе и после этого установить все новые подключения к главному серверу БД. Создать подключение к базе данных JDBC  я (могу, умею, практикую) , но с подобной задачей сталкиваюсь в первые , буду рад любой помощи и заранее благодарю

Comment: Интересно что обозначает  `без использование библиотек с открытым исходным кодом`? Нужно использовать библиотеки с закрытым кодом? Или вообще нельзя использовать библиотеки для менеджмента пула соединений...

Comment: без Spring , Hibernate итд

Answer (score 0):

В java для этого придумали пул потоков:

```
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        service.execute(new Thread(() -> {
            //some code
        }));
```

Если кол-во пула потоков ограничено, вы все равно можете попросить его выполнить какой-то поток, и как только какой-нибудь пул освободится, он приступит к выполнению. Для более быстрой рекурсивной обработки можете еще воспользоваться fork join-ом

Comment: Автор имеет в виду пул соединений (connection pool).